# Extruding vector using one of its attributes in GRASS?

Tags: openstreetmap, grass-gis, 3d, extrude

I'm following this tutorial: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Extrude_2D_polygons_to_3D.

This is what I've done so far (inside GRASS):

```
- Import a DEM HGT file:

> r.in.srtm input=S23W043.hgt --overwrite

- Edit osm_config.ini to include `height` as column. 
- export OSM_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/osm_config.ini
- Took an OSM file of a small region from https://www.openstreetmap.org/export
- Import the OSM data: 

 > v.in.ogr input=map.osm layer=multipolygons output=riodejaneiro2D where="building is not null and height is not null" --overwrite

- Adjust the region:

 > g.region vect=riodejaneiro2D

- Create a new column and copy data using cast because the height column is type=string:

 > v.db.addcolumn riodejaneiro2D col="altura integer"
 > v.db.update riodejaneiro2D col=altura qcol="CAST(height AS double precision)"

 - Extrude using the new column "altura" as parameter and the DEM raster as elevation:

 > v.extrude riodejaneiro2D out=riodejaneiro3D height_column=altura --overwrite elevation=S23W043 layer=multipolygons

 - Export as KML:

 > v.out.ogr input=riodejaneiro3D type=face output=riodejaneiro3D.kml format=KML --overwrite
```

In Google Earth I can see the KML features but all of them are flat. The same if I export as SHP file. This is what I have:

```
v.info riodejaneiro3D
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name:            riodejaneiro3D                                            |
 | Mapset:          PERMANENT                                                 |
 | Location:        magno01                                                   |
 | Database:        /home/magno/grass                                         |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Map scale:       1:1                                                       |
 | Name of creator: root                                                      |
 | Organization:                                                              |
 | Source date:     Thu Jun 13 23:30:26 2019                                  |
 | Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Map format:      native                                                    |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |   Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Number of points:       0               Number of centroids:  0          |
 |   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 0          |
 |   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
 |   Number of faces:        813248          Number of kernels:    93192      |
 |   Number of volumes:      0               Number of holes:      0          |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Map is 3D:              Yes                                              |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:   22:34:48.89316S    S:   23:03:11.51244S                 |
 |               E:   42:55:12.02052W    W:   43:34:47.97084W                 |
 |               B:                 0    T:                 0                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
 |     Generated by v.extrude from vector map <riodejaneiro2DCT@PERMANENT>    |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But... when I force a height using

```
v.extrude riodejaneiro2DCT out=riodejaneiro3D height=20 --overwrite
```

I can see the 3D features in Google Earth and the info changes to :

```
 |   Map is 3D:              Yes                                              |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:   22:34:48.89316S    S:   23:03:11.51244S                 |
 |               E:   42:55:12.02052W    W:   43:34:47.97084W                 |
 |               B:                 0    T:                20                 |
 |                                                                            |
```

Attention to the `T: 20`.

What I doing wrong to use one of the vector attributes as height to extrude it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

My mistake was in the new attribute field conversion. Must change

```
v.db.addcolumn riodejaneiro2D col="altura integer"
```

to

```
v.db.addcolumn riodejaneiro2D col="altura double precision"
```

Now I have

```
 |   Map is 3D:              Yes                                              |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:    22:53:35.3346S    S:   22:54:35.98344S                 |
 |               E:   43:10:29.50788W    W:   43:11:57.81624W                 |
 |               B:                 0    T:               143                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
```

[image]

and if you want to use my question/answer as a tutorial, you can fix the `Skipping area XXX without centroid` using:

```
v.centroids input=riodejaneiro2D output=riodejaneiro2DCT
```

and use `riodejaneiro2DCT` as the vector to extrude.

Comment: Looks cool! Please consider to accept your answer :)